# Error Styling action Bar android

Tags: android

From manifest: min version 14

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="14" 
     android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fondoObscuro</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/OnTheGoActionBar</item>

</style>


 <!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="OnTheGoActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item> 
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarObscura</item> 
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverflow</item>


</style>
```

I got the error no resource found, on both styles AppBaseTheme and OnTheGoActionBar

Comment: please post the log cat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very specific reason for having two seperate `values` folder especially for `theming the app

See as you can see in the code you posted, I am sure that following code is from `values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
</style>
```

I would like to draw your attention to commented code

**`Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in res/values-vXX/styles.xml`**

The `styles.xml` is for backward compatibility, you change the `parent` style 
`parent="android:Theme.Light"`  to `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

which is wrong since `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` was introduced in API Level-14, See here [Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar). The Builder looks for `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` , but it is not able to find it, as its applicable to new version and hence you see

`I got the error no resource found, on both styles AppBaseTheme and OnTheGoActionBar`

Simple move your code for custom styling to `values-v14\styles.xml` and everything will be fine, don't worry if you don't have style provided in `values\styles.xml`, untill and unless your `minSdkVersion` is 14.

I hope you understood it.

Comment: I think i got almost everything, i should move my code to te apropiate folder. But what should i put in styles then. T read "don't worry if you don't have style provided in values\styles.xml" so should i leave it blank?

Comment: yes you can, since your are specifically targeting app for higher APIs, styling will not that much be problem
accept answer it helped